# How do I define a base url which can be used in all the APIs

Tags: javascript, json

I have a set of APIs in my automation test which uses the request package. I want to have a common base URL so instead of changing the URL every time in all the APIs I can just change it in one place which will be used everywhere.

I have tried using the `$id` with `$ref` but I cannot seem to get it working. Any suggestion would be really appreciated as what is the best way to do it in a JSON file.

These are a few APIs that I have:

```
"create_api": https://url/receive/Test0/text?channel=Viber&sender.id=95
"attachment_api": "url/receive/Test0/attachment?channel=Viber&sender.id=95",
"sendmessage_api": "https://url/um/receive/Test0/text?channel=Viber&sender.id=95&text=New Message",
```

Instead of specifying the URL over and over again I want to specify it globally in the JSON file.

Comment: Please specify how you are reading this json file - is this a node.js server running express for example?
I would remove the base URL from all the API endpoints and either create `"base_url": "https://my_url.tld"` or pass in the base URL as an environment variable when starting the node server. This has the advantage that you can run this on localhost for testing without a problem

Comment: JSON has no concept of variables or string interpolation. Store it in a Javascript file instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be of many different approaches. The one which I follow is

```
var configuration = {
    "api": {
            "base": {
                "development": "http://localhost/",
                "test": "http://testserver.com/",
                "production": "productionserver.com/"
            },
            "login": "login/",
            "search": "questions/search/"
        }
}
```

and the way we can retrieve is

```
var environment = "development";
var loginurl = configuration.api.base[environment] + configuration.api.login;
var searchurl = configuration.api.base[environment] + configuration.api.search;
```